# Is it possible to normalize the web links dragging behavior of my web site?

Tags: php, jquery, drag-and-drop

I realize that the drag and drop behavior of web links is strongly dependent on the browser (I never used this before). For instance, consider the wikipedia link for beer from a google search of beer. If I use the Firefox and if I drag and drop the link in a text file, the entire content is copied to the text. Otherwise, if I use the chromium, it is only copied the link. I am using Ubuntu and I have no way to test (now) if the behavior in windows or mac is different.

From Chromium:

```
https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBeer&ei=Y97lVMH0C4HtgwS7koDwDA&usg=AFQjCNG9piVxLRqRNpjEJd09l8CQ0F-04w&bvm=bv.85970519,d.eXY
```

From Firefox:

```
<script>window.googleJavaScriptRedirect=1</script><script>var m={navigateTo:function(b,a,d){if(b!=a&&b.google){if(b.google.r){b.google.r=0;b.location.href=d;a.location.replace("about:blank");}}else{a.location.replace(d);}}};m.navigateTo(window.parent,window,"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer");
</script><noscript><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer'"></noscript>
```

Is it possible to normalize the behavior of this in my website using php or some solution using javascript or jquery? I would like that all browses behavior similar to chromium copying only the link!

Does it work for devices like iPad?

Comment: You are asking to control things that are outside of a browser window and therefore have no access to. What exactly is your objective?

Comment: My objective is to allow users to drag and drop links (in a specific place of my web site such as text field) that arise in my home page (for instance, similar to the link associated to the title of this question in stackoverflow). With this link, using regex, I can recover all the information about this link. If all the content is copied I am not able to recover the information I need.